# which() function in R

Tags: r

I have a data `frame(A)` of size (92047x2) and a `list(B)` of size (1829). I want to create a new data frame with all rows of A whose first column value is present in B.

How to use `which()`? Or any other good way to approach this?

All the values are in form of character. (Eg. "Vc2345")

Comment: this looks like a subsetting problem but without a piece of code or at least an expected output is hard to help you. Please refer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Read `help("%in%")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
dfA=data.frame(C1=sample(1:92047), C2=sample(1:92047))
listB=list(sample(1:1829))
dfAinB=dfA[which(dfA$C1 %in% unlist(listB)),]
str(dfAinB)
```